# Determine user quota for grandfathered Google Apps domains

Tags: google-workspace

As of Apr 28, 2011, Google has limited new Free Edition Google Apps deployments to 10 users, but older apps instances had their higher users limits grandfathered in (I have one deployment with 50 users and another with 20-something).

Google used to display the quota pretty obviously, but I can't find it now. Is there a way to determine how many free accounts I'll be able to create for a given domain?

Comment: Have you discovered this answer?

Comment: @Lynda, no, as far as I can tell, there's no way to determine the quote now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing, I ended up finding my quota after I saw your question. Basically login -> "Domain settings" menu -> then "Subscriptions & Billings" tab. Here's a screenshot of my account, I'm using 2 of my 50.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly enough, my domains don't have the "Subscription & Billing" tab at all.  Are you currently in the GA for Business 30 day trial period?

Comment: About a year ago I switched from personal to 30 trial of Business version, but after 2 weeks I switch back to the personal version - I've been on the personal version ever since.

Comment: My domains are now showing the same content yours did--I guess there was just a staged rollout of that feature at some point.

Answer (score 3):

In the new Admin console, just go to Billing from the main screen of the Admin console, and you will see the number of users you are using, and the total number of licenses (user quota):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no link to the Subscriptions & Billing page, but you can open it with the following link: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/example.com/DomainSettingsBillingInformation

Just replace example.com with your Google Apps domain.

Comment: Unfortunately for the free version that page just says "Total licenses purchased: 0", and does not show the total number of users that it will allow.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me at May 2014

1. Login to your google apps account
2. Navigate to https://admin.google.com/AdminHome
3. Select Billing
4. Number of available users are displayed.